# ZPL Horizontal Line

Tags: zpl

I'm looking for a way to do a horizontal line in ZPL.

I could do a vertical one with the ^GD command (^GD3,250,3,B,L)

And I did some bad horizontal one with that same command playing with width/height/thickness. But let's be honest, it looks like **** :D

Here is how it looks like :

[image]

Anyone having an idea ? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Doing the horizontal line with ^GD800,3,250,B,L , that is really bad looking !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `^GB` (graphic box) command and specify zero for the height.  For example, `^GB800,0,3,B` should get you a 3px horizontal line 800 pixels long.

Also use `^GB` for vertical lines, where you specify a zero width and a non-zero height.  For example, `^GB0,400,3,B` should render a 3px vertical line 400 pixels long.